# MS SQL Join ´table by first 6 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day

I have two tables

```
Table1 
Column1  Column2    
BoB      48J124BGAS11
Eva      V54318KFSGH5
John     465K33SH4674
Alex     7I7980HSH474

Table2 
Column1  Column2    
Apple    48J124
Samsung  V54318
Google   465K33
Android  348B00
Nokia    7I7980
Alcatel  158360
```

And I need Join them by firts 6 characters from right side of Column2. Expect result is like this.

```
Table3
Column1    Column2     Column3 
BoB      48J124BGAS11  Apple  
Eva      V54318KFSGH5  Samsung 
John     465K33SH4674  Google 
Alex     7I7980HSH474  7I7980
```

Iam not sure if i need create extra column in table1 for first 6 characters from right side of Column2 and then make join or i can create direct join.

Thanks for opinions.

Comment: No,  generally you needn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to create another column. Here's how you can join these tables:

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Coulmn1 FROM Table1 AS A
JOIN Table2 AS B ON B.Coulmn2 = LEFT(A.Column2, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Table2 always going to have 6 characters in Column2?

Its possible to use the LEFT function to limit the join to the specific characters you want to use in the join, like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON LEFT(T1.Column2,6) = LEFT(T2.Column2, 6)
```

The inner join will get the results that exits in both tables, just alter the select * to get the columns that you want.

The reason I put the LEFT pad on both conditions in the join is because I didn't know the table structure restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Use **substring**, on this way you can choose **start position** and **signs count**.

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Coulmn1 
FROM Table1 AS A
JOIN Table2 AS B 
ON B.Coulmn2 = substring(A.Column2,0,6)
```